# How to prevent image link open as image viewer - Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, image

I want users to click on an image on one of my pages and be taken to another website in a new tab or page.

But wordpress automatically open links in image viewer. What can I do prevent links opening as image viewer.

```
<a href="https://itunes.apple.com/" target="_blank">
<img class="size-full wp-image-1434 alignnone" src="http://3030.binaryhammer.com/images/appstore.png" alt="badge_app_store" width="165" height="49">
</a>
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you please send me your website link where i can check this issuse

Comment: Try the solution which i answered

Answer (score 0):

Remove class name "size-full wp-image-1434 alignnone" from image src then try

Hope it will work

Comment: But i can see its working in your site when you click on this image it goes to https://itunes.apple.com/ site. What you want ?. Are you click on the image above the socials media icons?

Answer (score 0):

You should have to disable default image links. 
Check this one : http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/automatically-remove-default-image-links-wordpress/